# Cannot access a disposed object Exception thrown when calling ReadAsStringAsync

Tags: c#, .net, exception

currently im facing a problem when calling the `ReadAsStringAsync()` Method on HttpResponseMessage. When i call the `GetAsync()` Method on the `HttpClient` class i read the Contents from the `Content` property with `ReadAsStringAsync()`. Normally i would get a JSON string returned, but i always get `System.ObjectDisposedException` thrown.

Setting the parameter disposeHandler on the `HttpClient` constructor to false still does not resolve the problem. The Code in particular:

```
internal async Task<T> HandleMessage<T>(HttpResponseMessage message)
        {
            string jsonContent = await message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); // Error on this line
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonContent); 
        }
```

I would pass the type and the the response message of the `GetAsync()`Method.

```
internal async Task<T> GetRequest<T>(string route)
        {
            var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(new Uri(_baseUrl,route));
            return await HandleMessage<T>(response);
        }
```

This is the Method i use to call the `HandleMessage` Method

EDIT:

I forgot some things to mention. Im currently calling the Nextcloud API. When i get a 401 Unauthorized the Exception gets thrown. This itself is not the Problem. I have the NetworkException() Method which takes the Exception and throws a custom Exception.
On a 200 Response Code everything works.

Additonal Code:

Here is my main method. From here i would call my Method GetAllUsers()

```
Uri url = new Uri("https://192.168.178.30");
            SiliconAuthentication siliconAuthentication = new SiliconAuthentication("cloudadmin", "token");
            SiliconCloud.SiliconCloud silicon = new SiliconCloud.SiliconCloud(url,siliconAuthentication);
            try
            {
                silicon.SiliconUserInstruction.GetAllUsers().Wait();
            }
            catch (SiliconNetworkException sne)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(sne.Message + Environment.NewLine + "Meta Message: " + sne.MetaMessage + Environment.NewLine+"Meta Statuscode: " + sne.StatusCode);
            }
```

Declaring the route and calling the GetRequest Method:

```
public async Task<SiliconOCSResponse<SiliconResponseAvailableUser>> GetAllUsers()
    {
        string apiRoute = "/ocs/v2.php/cloud/users";
        return await _siliconNetwork.GetRequest<SiliconOCSResponse<SiliconResponseAvailableUser>>(apiRoute);
    }
```

Calling the GetRequest with the api route

```
internal async Task<T> GetRequest<T>(string route)
        {
            
            var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(new Uri(_baseUrl, route));
            try
            {
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            }
            catch (HttpRequestException eax) // A HTTP error occurs
            {
                await NetworkException(route, response, eax);  
            }

            return await HandleMessage<T>(response);
        }
```

Network Exception Method throwing a custom exception

```
internal async Task NetworkException(string route, HttpResponseMessage message, HttpRequestException innerEx)
        {
            var ms = await message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); // Error here
            throw new SiliconNetworkException($"Unknown Network Error occured trying to connect to {route}. See Inner Exception for more information",
                innerEx,
               JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SiliconOCSResponse<List<string>>>(ms)
                );
        }
```

As requested here is the constructor where the HttpClient is initialized

```
public SiliconNetwork(Uri url, SiliconAuthentication siliconAuth)
        {
            // https://github.com/nextcloud/server/issues/7753 
            _httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { UseCookies = false });
            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(ContentType.TypeJSON));
            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{siliconAuth.UserName}:{siliconAuth.Password}")));
            this._httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("OCS-APIRequest", "true");
            this._baseUrl= url;
            this._siliconAuthentication = siliconAuth;
            
        }
```

Additionally the stack trace:

```
at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.CheckDisposed()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.ReadAsStringAsync()
   at SiliconCloud.Network.SiliconNetwork.<NetworkException>d__22.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Weasel\source\repos\Silicon\SiliconCloud\Network\SiliconNetwork.cs:line 233
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at SiliconCloud.Network.SiliconNetwork.<GetRequest>d__16`1.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Weasel\source\repos\Silicon\SiliconCloud\Network\SiliconNetwork.cs:line 174
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at SiliconCloud.UserManagement.UserProvisioning.SiliconUserInstruction.<GetAllUsers>d__17.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Weasel\source\repos\Silicon\SiliconCloud\UserManagement\UserProvisioning\SiliconUserInstruction.cs:line 278
```

Comment: There's probably a missing `await` somewhere further up the call stack. Please post a minimal repro.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: i edited the original post. should be more code to see now

Comment: Your problem starts here: `silicon.SiliconUserInstruction.GetAllUsers().Wait();` and is finalized here: `response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();`. This is meant to throw and dispose of the resources it handled. Check `IsSuccessStatusCode` instead and await async calls -- The other problem, which can be huge but it can also be use-case specific, is the way the HttpClient object is declared. This class is meant to be reused, it's usually declared as a `static readonly` object and disposed only when not needed anymore. Not clear what's the case here, how the HttpClient object is handled

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Jimi in the comments the problem seems to be with `EnsureSucessStatusCode()` Method which disposes everything after the Exception gets thrown.

```
internal async Task<T> GetRequest<T>(string route)
    {   
        var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(new Uri(_baseUrl, route));
        if(!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            await NetworkException(route, response);
        }
        return await HandleMessage<T>(response);
    }
```